# Tablet Device Dimensions imply orientation?

Tags: android, hardware

So this is a out of the box question ..

I wanted to know; do the dimensions of a android tablet imply its orientation ??

In other words I have a android tablet, with X width, and Y height.

If X > Y does this imply that the orientation of the screen is in landscape
and X < Y imply the screen is portrait??

I think this is the case .. just need confirmation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Landscape is just defined as width>height.